# Selenium: Drag and drop not working on safari

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, selenium2library

I've made a simple function to drag and drop, similar to the one already existing but with some improvements, such function works perfectly on Chrome(61) and Firefox, both in background or foreground with no distinction.

But on Safari nothing seems to happen when using it

Function:

```
def drag_from_x_to_y_by_offset(locator, startOffX, startOffY, endOffX, endOffY):
    driver = get_wb()

    elem = sn.Safari.find_element_by_class_name(driver, locator)
    ac = sn.ActionChains(driver)

    ac.move_to_element(elem).move_by_offset(startOffX, startOffY).click_and_hold()
    .move_by_offset(endOffX,endOffY).release().perform()
```

get_wb() just gives the current instance of the browser, every other command works just fine

Usage in robot framework:

```
<appropriate loading and checks for readiness>
drag from x to y by offset  ${canvas_class}  -100  -100  100  100
```

EDIT: The normal drag and drop seems not to be working either
EDIT2: No error is returned by any function